# Flex-Basis is not working

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive

I have 3 items,    and I'm trying to use flex-basis to make them occupy 20% 20% and 60% (in this order) of the screen side by side and when the window size decrease they get in a column, the thing is my flex-basis is doing nothing, I removed it and it stayed just equal as it is right now, some help?

HTML:

```
<section class="number2">
<h2 class="white">The Scoville Scale</h2>
<article class="two"> The Scoville Unit (SHU) scale is a method of
quantifying a substance's 'spiciness', through determining the concentration
of the chemical compounds responsible for the sensation, which are named
capsaicinoids. We have American chemist Wilbur Scoville to thank for the
scale that rates the chillies we chomp. In 1912, long before high-pressure
liquid chromatography tests in labs, he relied on taste alone. A grain of
chilli was dissolved in an alcoholic solution added to sweetened water until
it could barely be noted by a panel of testers. The more dilution required,
the higher the rating.
</article>
<figure class="tes">
<img src="https://www.alimentarium.org/en/system/files/styles/full_wide/private/thumbnails/image/EMAG_INFO_piment_scoville_EN.png?itok=IqE8GNK6">
</figure>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.number2 {
  background-color: #df506e;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

}

.white {
  color: white;
  flex-basis: 20%;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}

.two {
  flex-basis: 20%;
  color: white;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}

.tes {
  flex-basis:60%;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

Comment: Read his https://codepen.io/townivan/post/flexbox-flex-direction-column

Comment: You'll also need a media query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go.

I'd rather use the flex shorthand of `flex:1 0 x%`. Then it's a matter of resetting any default margins (especially on the `figure`) and a media query.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.number2 {
  background-color: #df506e;
  display: flex;
}

.white {
  color: white;
  flex: 1 0 20%;
}

.two {
  color: white;
  flex: 1 0 20%;
}

.tes {
  margin: 0;
  flex: 1 0 60%;
}

.tes img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .number2 {
    background-color: rebeccapurple;
    /* for demo purposes */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="number2">
  <h2 class="white">The Scoville Scale</h2>
  <article class="two">
    <p>The Scoville Unit (SHU) scale is a method of quantifying a substance's 'spiciness', through determining the concentration of the chemical compounds responsible for the sensation, which are named capsaicinoids. We have American chemist Wilbur Scoville
      to thank for the scale that rates the chillies we chomp. In 1912, long before high-pressure liquid chromatography tests in labs, he relied on taste alone. A grain of chilli was dissolved in an alcoholic solution added to sweetened water until it
      could barely be noted by a panel of testers. The more dilution required, the higher the rating.</p>
  </article>
  <figure class="tes">
    <img src="https://www.alimentarium.org/en/system/files/styles/full_wide/private/thumbnails/image/EMAG_INFO_piment_scoville_EN.png?itok=IqE8GNK6">
  </figure>
</section>
```

[**Codepen demo**](https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/BrGrvm?editors=1100)